# Creating a new skin class for a ToggleButton

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I'm using the following Flex component: http://flashcommander.org/blog/flex-4-mp3-player

The skin that comes with this component only allows for very basic skinning, such as background colour and borders. However the component makes use of a `ToggleButton`, defined in `Mp3Player.as`:

```
import spark.components.ToggleButton;
[SkinPart]
public var playPauseButton:ToggleButton;
```

What I would like to do is define an alternative skin for this control in the project, I'm pretty new to Flex and Spark so I'm un-sure as to how I go about define a new skin.

In the `Mp3PlayerSkin.mxml` file the skin is defined as follows:

```
    <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#playPauseButton -->
    <s:ToggleButton id="playPauseButton" left="0" bottom="0" 
            skinClass="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.normal.PlayPauseButtonSkin" 
            focusIn="event.target.depth=1" focusOut="event.target.depth=0" />
```

I assume I can create a new `class`, although I don't know how to do that, or remove the reference to the class and extend the `ToggleButton` skin in some way. I'm thinking I need to override the 'default' skin in some way?

Any pointers appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can do the following:

1. Create a new Flex Skin by right-clicking the original `Mp3PlayerSkin.mxml` file
2. Name the file `toggleButtonSkin.mxml`
3. Copy the styles from the `spark.components.VideoPlayer#playPauseButton` class
4. Update the `Mp3PlayerSkin.mxml` as follows:

   ```
   <s:ToggleButton id="playPauseButton" left="0" bottom="0" 
           skinClass="org.flashcommander.components.toggleButtonSkin" 
           focusIn="event.target.depth=1" focusOut="event.target.depth=0" />
   ```

Now I can edit the new `toggleButtonSkin.mxml` file by editing the new styles.